# How to pass request to a Field Serializer in Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi I am using a Field Serializer to be able to serialize a PK field then deserialize it as object. Inside the serializer is a `SerializerMethodField` to build a custom url. It works when I use the itself from serializing its own record. However when I use it to a different serializer as a `FieldSerializer`, the `request` object is not passed.

```
class TelemetryFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    telemetry_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='name', queryset=TelemetryFileType.objects.all())
    receiving_station = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        required=False, slug_field='name', queryset=ReceivingStation.objects.all())
    link = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TelemetryFile
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_link(self, object):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        print(self.context)   # request is not passed here from RawImageSerializer/TelemetryFileField
        return request.build_absolute_uri('/data_management/telemetry_files/{}'.format(object.id))


class TelemetryFileField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        pk = super(TelemetryFileField, self).to_representation(value)
        item = TelemetryFile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = TelemetryFileSerializer(item)
        return serializer.data


class RawImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    from_telemetry_file = TelemetryFileField(queryset=TelemetryFile.objects.all())
    link = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

I want to pass a request of itself to be able to create a url of it.
This is the returned when I use the `RawImageSerializer`:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'build_absolute_uri'

There must be a way to pass `request` from serializer to another...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct solution but adding this solved my problem...

```
class TelemetryFileField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        print("value", self.context)
        pk = super(TelemetryFileField, self).to_representation(value)
        item = TelemetryFile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = TelemetryFileSerializer(item, context=self.context) # context was added
        return serializer.data
```